# How to add enum using property attribute and property drawer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

property attribute script

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public enum GapDisplayMode
{
    Integers,
    Floats
}

public class GapRangeAttribute : PropertyAttribute
{
    public float minRange;
    public float maxRange;
    public GapDisplayMode displayMode;

    public GapRangeAttribute(float minRange, float maxRange, GapDisplayMode displayMode)
    {
        this.minRange = minRange;
        this.maxRange = maxRange;
        this.displayMode = displayMode;
    }
}
```

the property drawer script

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(GapRangeAttribute))]
public class GapRangeDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        GapRangeAttribute gapRange = attribute as GapRangeAttribute;

        if (property.propertyType == SerializedPropertyType.Float)
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

            Rect popupPosition = new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight);
            Rect sliderPosition = new Rect(position.x, position.y + EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight + EditorGUIUtility.standardVerticalSpacing, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight);

            gapRange.displayMode = (GapDisplayMode)EditorGUI.EnumPopup(popupPosition, "Display Mode", gapRange.displayMode);

            if (gapRange.displayMode == GapDisplayMode.Integers)
            {
                int intValue = EditorGUI.IntSlider(sliderPosition, label, Mathf.RoundToInt(property.floatValue), (int)gapRange.minRange, (int)gapRange.maxRange);
                property.floatValue = intValue;
            }
            else
            {
                float floatValue = EditorGUI.Slider(sliderPosition, label, property.floatValue, gapRange.minRange, gapRange.maxRange);
                property.floatValue = floatValue;
            }

            EditorGUI.EndProperty();
        }
        else
        {
            EditorGUI.LabelField(position, label.text, "Use [GapRangeDrawer] with float values only!");
        }
    }
}
```

using it in mono

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class CubeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubePrefab;
    public LayerMask terrainLayer;
    [GapRange(0, 100, GapDisplayMode.Floats)]
    public float gap = 0f;
```

the problem is that when the enum GapDisplayMode in the GapRangeAttribute display in the inspector the range slider in the GapRangeDrawer script is overlapping on variable from the mono script in the editor inspector.

marked with red circle the overlapping.

[image: overlap]

I also tried this approach , but it didn't change much with the problem. I created this script and tried to make also changes to the drawer but it didn't change much so i went back to the original scripts above.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(CubeSpawner))]
public class CubeSpawnerEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty gapProperty;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        gapProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("gap");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        CubeSpawner cubeSpawner = (CubeSpawner)target;

        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("cubePrefab"));
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("terrainLayer"));

        GapDisplayMode displayMode = cubeSpawner.displayMode;
        displayMode = (GapDisplayMode)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Display Mode", displayMode);

        EditorGUILayout.Space();

        if (displayMode == GapDisplayMode.Floats)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.Slider(gapProperty, cubeSpawner.minFloatRange, cubeSpawner.maxFloatRange, "Gap");
        }
        else if (displayMode == GapDisplayMode.Integers)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.IntSlider(gapProperty, (int)cubeSpawner.minIntRange, (int)cubeSpawner.maxIntRange, "Gap");
        }

        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("cameraMoveSpeed"));
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("zoomSpeed"));
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("rotationSpeed"));

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your property requires more then a single line in the Inspector you have to implement [`GetPropertyHeight`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.GetPropertyHeight.html) like e.g.

```
public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
{
    return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * property.propertyType == SerializedPropertyType.Float ? 2 : 1;
}
```

within your `GapRangeDrawer`

Comment: some erros.  on GetPropertyHeight no suitable metho found to override and on the property inside not exist.  the method I added it after the OnGUI and if I try to put in the method GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property) then in the line iside on the left side I get error cannot operand type of float and SerializedProperty.

Comment: This method working public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) { } but inside the line you provided give error on the left side.  cannot operand type of float and SerializedProperty

Comment: @DanielLip I was only on the phone ^^ of course I meant to use the signature it has to have ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfect.

```
public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        // Check if the property type is float
        if (property.propertyType == SerializedPropertyType.Float)
        {
            return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 2; // Add an empty line, adjust the value as needed
        }

        return base.GetPropertyHeight(property, label);
    }
```